# If $g(x)$ is strictly increasing, then $g(x)+ah(x)$ is also strictly increasing for some small positive constant $a$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions, bounded-variation

Suppose that $g(x)$ is strictly increasing; $g,h$ are smooth functions. Both $g,h$ are defined on a closed interval $I$.

Can we claim that $f(x)=g(x)+ah(x)$ is also strictly increasing for some small positive constant $a$?

**Here is my "proof":**

Since $g,h$ are smooth and $I$ is closed, then $g'(x),h'(x)$ are bounded variation functions.

Define: $$\min_{x\in I} h'(x)=c$$ $$\min g'(x)=b>0$$

By setting $a<b/|c|$, it is obvious that $f'(x)>0$?

---

Thank you for the counterexample; the claim was wrong. I think in order to have the claim correct, **we must further require that $g'(x)>0$ for that closed interval $I$**, rather than just being "strictly increase"?

Comment: A strictly increasing function can have a derivative of $0$ at some point, for example $f(x) =x^3$.

Comment: @MattSamuel I think in order to have the claim correct, we must further require that $g'(x)>0$ for that closed interval $I$, rather than just being "strictly increase".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not true that $\min g'(x) > 0$.

Hint: try $g(x) = x^2$ and $h(x) = -x$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Thank you for the smart counterexample. I think in order to have the claim correct, we must further require that $g'(x)>0$ for that closed interval $I$, rather than just being "strictly increase".